# for loops, and images

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I need a for loop to call an image. I knew how to call the image via an array so I set up a basic array with the image link in it. I can't seem to get it to work though. below is the relevant javascript and the image of what is trying to be accomplished

```
function icon(x) {
    var img = new Array();
    img[0] = {img:"img/icon1.gif"};
    var icon =" <img src='" + img[x].img + "'>";
    for(var i=30; i<31; i++) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += icon + i;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you start a loop at `30`?

Comment: @BenM And it ends at `30` too. Shortest loop ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep calling the icons from an array like the way you currently are, you can use something like this. However, like @lwalden said, you don't need to use an array.

```
function icon(){
    var img = new Array();
    img[0] = {img: "img/icon1.gif"};
    var icon = img[0];
    for(var i=0; i < 30; i++){
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += i+1 + ' ' + icon + '<br />';
    }
}

function icon2(){
    var img = new Array();
    img[0] = {img: "img/icon1.gif"};
    img[1] = {img: "img/icon2.gif"};
    for(var i=0; i < 30; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            icon = img[0];
        else
            icon = img[1];
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += i+1 + ' ' + icon + '<br />';
    }
}

// Prints the specified icon 30 times
icon();

// Alternates icon 1 and 2 30 times
icon2();
```

The output will also display which increment you're on. The second function is fairly similar except it just checks whether the current increment is even or odd with the modulus(`%`) operator. It will print icon 1 on the first increment (starting at 0) and icon 2 on the second increment and alternate respectively.

Comment: Yeah i had actually only used an array because I knew how to add an image using the arrays, and used what i thought might work. however as you mention the arrays are not needed and it's easier to do it without them now that i understand this a little better

Comment: I also just tweaked this code to use it without arrays, I think I have a good grip on this concept between what you and @lwalden have shown me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the link once, have a for loop cause the icon1 image display 30 times.

Okay - first your for loop is only running once - you initialize i as 30 and loop until i is no longer less than 31, incrimenting by 1 each time, so it will run once, increment from 30 to 31 then break out of the loop.

Also not sure why your image is contained in an array, unless that's some separate requirement, especially since there's only one image in the array.

You could refactor to something like this:

```
function showIconThirtyTimes(){
    var icon ="<img src='img/icon1.gif'>"

    for(var i=0; i<30; i++) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += icon;
    }
}
```

If you need to have the image stored in an array, or if you need to write to the document the counter `i` you should be able to add those requirements back in pretty easily. The main problem was your `for` loop.